# Cannot access field with arrays in vuetable-2

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2

I have the following JSON array and using vuetable-2 in vue.js

[image]

In fields, I have

```
fields: [
            {
               name: 'name',
               title: 'Name'
            },
            {
               name: 'roles',
               title: 'Roles'
            }

         ],
```

There is no value displayed for **Roles** column.

But I can access the array in cell-clicked

```
<vuetable ref="vuetable"
      :api-url="url"
      :http-options="headerOptions"
      fields="fields"
      pagination-path=""
      :css="css.table"
      :multi-sort="true"
      @vuetable:pagination-data="onPaginationData">
```

Also in DetailRow.vue, I can access the same array

```
<template>
    <div @click="onClick">
        <div class="inline field">
            <label>Description: </label>
            <span>{{rowData.name}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="inline field">
            <label>Role: </label>
            <span>{{rowData.roles[0].roles}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

How do I directly access the array in the table column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name option in field definition does not support array referencing but the **callback** function can solve the problem. If you want to show **roles** then try this.

```
fields: [
            {
               name: 'name',
               title: 'Name'
            },
            {
               name: 'roles',
               title: 'Roles',
               callback: 'getRole',
            }

         ],
```

Method should be like below

```
methods: {
            getRole(value) {
                return value[0].roles;
            },
}
```